# Why is my Extjs Model/Record holding only it's Id field when the network traffic and .NET display full record?

Tags: forms, extjs, model, record, network-traffic

I'm having a rather strange bug/problem here that I cannot seem to figure out.

On the double-click event of my grid I am sending a request to my Api controller with an Id to get me a single "Contract" record to load into a form on the ExtJs side. The .NET debugging sends back the correct "Contract" record with all fields.

The network traffic also shows that the record has been retrieved with all fields as shown below.
[image: Network Traffic For The Record]

However, when logging the record in the success callback of my load I only have the ID field. [image: Console Log For The Record]

This then means when loading my record into my form none of the fields are shown.

The model is show below,

```
Ext.define('Heating.model.contract.Contract', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',

    fields: [
        { name: 'id', type: 'auto' },
        { name: 'organisationId', type: 'auto' },
        { name: 'organisation', type: 'auto' },
        { name: 'systemTypeId', type: 'auto' },
        { name: 'systemType', type: 'auto' },
        { name: 'description', type: 'auto' },
        { name: 'deleted', type: 'auto' },
        { name: 'startDate', type: 'date' },
        { name: 'endDate', type: 'date' },
        { name: 'lastModified', type: 'date', dateFormat: 'c' }

    ],

    validations: [
      { type: 'presence', field: 'description'},
      { type: 'length',   field: 'description',  max: 255},
      { type: 'presence', field: 'organisationId'}
    ],

    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        url: Heating.util.Config.BaseUrl + 'api/contract',
        noCache: true,
        filterParam: 'filter',
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'data',
            totalProperty: 'total',
            messageProperty: 'message'
        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json'
        }
    }
});
```

And store,

```
Ext.define('Heating.store.contract.Contracts', {

extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
model: 'Heating.model.contract.Contract',
storeId: 'contracts',
autoLoad: false,
remoteFilter: true,
listeners: {
    load: function(store, records) {
        console.log('Contract store loaded');
        console.log(store.getCount());
    }
}
});
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does `Heating.model.contract.Contract` look like? Could also have something to do with the proxies defined `Ext.data.Reader`

Comment: agree with @Geronimo, if you could add the model & store code from extjs with proxy, that would help.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys, these have been added to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data` property in this image looks wrong to me.

[image: Network Traffic For The Record]

Seems like your records are inside of an array that are inside of another array. Like this (*incorrect*):

```
{
success: true,
total: 1,
message: 'blah blah blah',
data: 
    [
        [
           {
           id: "record-1",
           //etc
           }, {
           id: "record-2",
           //etc
           }
        ]
    ]
}
```

The data root should be a single array of record objects being returned from the server side, something like this: (*correct*)

```
{
success: true,
total: 1,
message: 'blah blah blah',
data: 
    [
        {
        id: "record-1",
        //etc
        }, {
        id: "record-2",
        //etc
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Spot on mate thankyou! My logic was sending back a list item which contained another list item with a single object.